# Snytax for accessing multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I am trying to connect to a linkedin api and this is almost embarassing to ask but I just cant seem to get the syntax correct for accessing a multidimensional array. When I print out the full $information variable I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [person] => Array
        (
            [id] => vlofsVJ8FM
            [first-name] => Tyler
            [last-name] => Slater
            [interests] => Golf, Motorcycles, Technology
        ) 
)
```

So when I go to try and reference the id I would normally say $information['person']['id'] but then it doesn't return anything. Sorry for the noob question but I just can't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have more arrays, so select the first

```
$information[0]['person']['id']
```

Comment: As I implement this is only returns Array
(
    [person] => 
)     Even when I only ask for $information[0]['person']

Comment: That too returns Array ( [person] => )

Comment: Im thinking the problem is somewhere else because its interpreting it as xml later on. Give me a second and I'll see if I can identify what part I really need to copy over

Comment: Got it! It wasn't quite what I was thinking what it was going to be but thank you for the guidelines and I did use that snippet later on in my code

Answer (score 2):

```
$information[0]['person']['element_name'];
```

---

Another way to get the data you need from this data structure can be done using the `current` function:

```
$information = current($information);
```

Then you can access the elements you need by using `$information['id']`

Comment: or you can use $information = current($information) to set the information array to the first element

Comment: yes, pulling the current array into $information ($information = current($information)) you can then access the element you want by using $information['id'] or whatever element you want. Or you can access it from my original answer and @Fabio's. It's another way of accessing the data

Comment: Add that to your answer.